# Accidentally deleted mysql-server

Tags: mysql

I wanted to have a clean installation of Mysql-server, so I followed the steps of this tutorial to remove completely MySQL:
https://help.cloud66.com/node/how-to-guides/databases/shells/uninstall-mysql.html

The command that seems very bogus to me in the tutorial is the following :

```
sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Unfortunately, I did not manage to reinstall mysql using the normal steps:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-commons mysql-client mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

The errors I get :

`sudo mysql_secure_installation` outputs :
`sudo: mysql_secure_installation: command not found`

I found that the file `/etc/init.d/mysql` is not created. I have tried to create it myself, but the `mysql` command does not output anything.

Any thought on how to approach this?

Comment: I'm not sure that MySQL is something that can properly be described as being 'installed'

Comment: Yes I should probably should use the term "mysql-server", but the command I am trying to run is "mysql"

Comment: How do you reinstall, and when you do are there any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Olamide226 had the right answer:

The purge step in the removing of mysql server did not work properly:
`sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common` outputs `Some packages could not be installed. The following packages have unmet dependencies: dbconfig-mysql : Depends: default-mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or virtual-mysql-client`

I needed to run `sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client` and purge again to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following...(assuming that mysql is completely removed)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try to run this, I am getting the following error message :
`sudo: mysql_secure_installation: command not found`

Comment: At this step in the process `sudo systemctl status mysql` outputs `mysql.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)`

Comment: It's because mysql was not removed completely.

First, remove MySQL:

sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*

Comment: The `remove` and `purge` command outputs the following error: `Some packages could not be installed. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbconfig-mysql : Depends: default-mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or
                           virtual-mysql-client`